# addListener to chrome.commands.onCommand from ClojureScript not triggering function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, clojurescript

I have the following code, in a new extension I am working on:

```
(.addListener js/chrome.alarms.onAlarm (fn [alarm] (.log js/console alarm)))
(.addListener js/chrome.commands.onCommand (fn [command] (.log js/console command)))
(.addListener js/chrome.browserAction.onClicked (fn [] (.log js/console "clicked!")))
```

My `:cljsbuild` looks like this:

```
{:id "background"
 :source-paths ["src/folder/background"]
 :compiler {:output-dir "resources/public/js/compiled/background"
            :output-to "resources/public/js/compiled/background/background.js"
            :main folder.background.background
            :optimizations :advanced
            :pretty-print true
            :source-map "resources/public/js/compiled/background/background.js.map"
            :externs ["resources/public/js/chrome_extensions.js"]}}
```

The code is exactly in the order shown. The bizarre thing is that the first and third lines work, while the second does nothing. My `manifest.json` (relevant parts) looks like this (there is no parsing error):

```
"background": {
  "scripts": [
    "path/to/compiled/file.js"
  ]
},
"permissions": [
  "alarms",
  "commands"
],
"commands": {
  "do-something": {
    "suggested_key": {
      "default": "Alt+Shift+D"
    },
    "description": "Do it!"
  }
}
```

I have advanced compilation on and I have the correct extern file (have tested this. Unlikely to be the issue).

Last, but not least, I did a JavaScript version of this and the same thing works. How can it be??

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function (command) {
    console.log(command);
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at the compiled script and compare it to the working version.

Comment: I did that and the output is the same! That's the most weird part. Maybe something wrong with my `:cljsbuild`? I don't know where else to look. Will try to construct a raw version using only `cljs.jar` to see if I get any luck.

Comment: Indeed it seems to be something related to my setup. Using just the `cljs.jar` I managed to make the command execute as expected. I'll dig a bit more to see if I can figure the source of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it seems to be something related to my setup.

I abandoned the previous setup I was using (with `lein` and `cljsbuild`) and started from scratch using only `cljs.jar` (take a look at the [repo](https://github.com/marcelocra/chrome-extension-cljs-example)) as suggested in the [Quickstart](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start).

I will build this from the ground up, until I figure what the problem was. Then I can post it here in case no one find a solution first.

Thanks!